# EF Core updating multiple entities within one database access or split them up

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the to decide about the following problem:

2 Objects (i.e. Order and Budget, here simplified):

```
class Order {
  double Price;
}

class Budget{
   double InternalBudget;
   double ProjectBudget;
}
```

Now the following question:
When a new order is added, the budget has to be updated too.
Now, what is the better approach:

Doing both in one dataAccess-method, like:

```
Order SaveOrderAndUpdateRemainingBudget(Order order, budget updateBudget)
{
  // add/update both to DB and dbContext.SaveChanges()
}
```

or

```
Order UpdateOrder(Order order)
{
  // update order
}

Budget UpdateBudget(Budget budget)
{
  // update budget and dbContext.SaveChanges()
}
```

My thoughts about the second approach: if updating the budget fails, I have an inconsistent DB state, the order is inserted but the budget has an outdated value.

Any suggestions on the best way of handling that?

Comment: EF uses a transaction to make sure that all database updates are written at the same time (ACID).  All you need to do is make sure SaveChanges/SaveChangesAsync happen once only, after all the updates have been done.

Comment: It might be worth considering a DB trigger.

Comment: @KieranDevlin - consider a trigger and then run away screaming!!
I consider them to be evil and to be avoided in almost all circumstances; there's almost always a better way to do things without resorting to triggers, which inevitably cause problems when people don't realise they're there. Keep the logic in your app.

Comment: @Mog0 That's poor and anecdotal advice. I agree that you should keep business logic outside of the DB where you can, but sometimes it makes sense from a design, perf and simplicity standpoint.

Comment: @KieranDevlin my comment was semi-jokey but in my 20 years of building complex web applications, the only thing I've ever found works better with triggers is tracking the history of changes for every table in the database. I've removed many triggers to consolidate the app logic and never had any loss of performance, usually it's performed better.
This is anecdotal and I'm sure there are certain things that triggers can work well with but I believe these to be the exception and in general a well structured repository pattern can do the job better.
Of course others will have different opinions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do is have the UpdateOrder and UpdateBudget methods like you have, but they don't save in those methods. So you would do it like so...

```
 UpdateOrder(order);
 UpdateBudget(budget);
 dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

That way the order is encapsulated in its own repository and budget is in another.
Then save changes finishes it off.

Your option 2 will create problems like you say.

Each entity should be in charge of itself and know nothing about other entities unless absolutely necessary. Remember that methods should only do one thing in an ideal world, try to approach it with that in mind.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What I still worry about is, that I have a Coordinator-class (handling the operations on the order before it can be saved + triggers the calculation of new budget) that calls the DataAccess class in order to update/save the entities. 
  The Coordinator does not have access to the dbContext. So I would still have to call a method doing the two operations and dbContext.Save(). I would still consider it cleaner than any of the other two approaches.

Comment: I use a unit of work/repository pattern for my approach to solve this to make it nice and clean if you look that up on google, Microsoft do a post on it. Also if anyone  tells you that the unit of work pattern is redundant because the db context is a unit of work then they're wrong, because the point of repositories is that it can do things such as logging all within a class that doesn't touch the service layer (your coordinator class would be the service layer).

So from my understanding your DataAccess class is the repositories here, so all you need is another layer which is a unit of work

Comment: Also if you really don't like the unit of work approach, then if you're using dependency injection (which you should be with Ef-core) the DbContext class is scoped, therefore if you call SaveChanges in the UpdateBudget method but not the UpdateOrder it will save any changes you made in UpdateOrder. I wouldnt reccomend this approach however, but it's up to you.

Comment: Had a look at the unit of work pattern, looks indeed nice and clean! Thank you!